# Arquillian JPA tutorial: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor

Tags: maven, jpa, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I finished following the JPA tutorial at http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/ , but when I try to run the test ("Run the Test on GlassFish" section of the guide) as JUnit I obtain the following messages in Eclipse's console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerCreationException: Could not create Container glassfish-embedded
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:56)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeployableContainer must be specified
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:44)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:71)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:76)
    ... 39 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>arquillian-tutorial</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>imagecomparison</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <profile>
      <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
      <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
          <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
      <testResources>
          <testResource>
          <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
          </testResource>
          <testResource>
          <directory>src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded</directory>
          </testResource>
      </testResources>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.12</version>
          <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
              <java.util.logging.config.file>
                  ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
              </java.util.logging.config.file>
              <derby.stream.error.file>
                  ${project.build.directory}/derby.log
              </derby.stream.error.file>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
</project>
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="resourcesXml">
                src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

**Game.java**

```
package org.arquillian.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Game implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    public Game() {}

    public Game(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Game@" + hashCode() + "[id = " + id + "; title = " + title + "]";
    }
}
```

**GamePersistenceTest.java**

```
package org.arquillian.example;


import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.Assert;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;


@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GamePersistenceTest {
    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addPackage(Game.class.getPackage())
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    private static final String[] GAME_TITLES = {
        "Super Mario Brothers",
        "Mario Kart",
        "F-Zero"
    };

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    UserTransaction utx;

    // tests go here

    @Before
    public void preparePersistenceTest() throws Exception {
        clearData();
        insertData();
        startTransaction();
    }

    private void clearData() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
        System.out.println("Dumping old records...");
        em.createQuery("delete from Game").executeUpdate();
        utx.commit();
    }

    private void insertData() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
        System.out.println("Inserting records...");
        for (String title : GAME_TITLES) {
            Game game = new Game(title);
            em.persist(game);
        }
        utx.commit();
        // clear the persistence context (first-level cache)
        em.clear();
    }

    private void startTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
    }
    @After
    public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.commit();
    }

    private static void assertContainsAllGames(Collection<Game> retrievedGames) {
        Assert.assertEquals(GAME_TITLES.length, retrievedGames.size());
        final Set<String> retrievedGameTitles = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Game game : retrievedGames) {
            System.out.println("* " + game);
            retrievedGameTitles.add(game.getTitle());
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(retrievedGameTitles.containsAll(Arrays.asList(GAME_TITLES)));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFindAllGamesUsingCriteriaApi() throws Exception {
        // given
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Game> criteria = builder.createQuery(Game.class);

        Root<Game> game = criteria.from(Game.class);
        criteria.select(game);
        // TIP: If you don't want to use the JPA 2 Metamodel,
        // you can change the get() method call to get("id")
        criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(game.get(Game_.id)));
        // No WHERE clause, which implies select all

        // when
        System.out.println("Selecting (using Criteria)...");
        List<Game> games = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

        // then
        System.out.println("Found " + games.size() + " games (using Criteria):");
        assertContainsAllGames(games);
    }


}
```

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: no and for the moment I am trying to set up JPA-JTA on Java EE environment

Comment: thank you for the reply. I've wasted a lot of time configuring gradle+arquillian+embedded glassfish, but, unfortunately, didn't find a right solution to run my tests.

Answer (score 4):

The pom.xml of the project has some of the profiles like arquillian-weld-ee-embedded, arquillian-glassfish-embedded, and arquillian-jbossas-managed.and none of them is active by default,so to make the Arquillian container workable,you need to make any of these profile default.
check the following pom.xml

```
           `  <dependenies>
              <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-jbossas-embedded</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: where is arquillian-jbossas-embedded?

Comment: ìf you are not using jboss ,then you can mark any other profile default,and that should work