# Game_ cannot be resolved to a variable in arquillian persistance example

Tags: eclipse, m2e, jboss-arquillian

I was asking on #arquillian Freenode IRC channel about question

[Arquillian JPA tutorial: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931491/arquillian-jpa-tutorial-could-not-create-new-instance-of-class-org-jboss-arquil)

when a user told me that he successfully runned

https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples/tree/master/arquillian-persistence-tutorial

so I did

```
git clone https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples.git
```

then in Eclipse, I clicked File->Import->Existing Maven Projects and selecte the subdirectory

```
arquillian-examples/arquillian-persistence-tutorial
```

Once Eclipse finished importing the project, I obtain in file

`/src/test/java/org/arquillian/example/GamePersistenceTest.java`

line 146, the error message

> Game_ cannot be resolved to a variable

What can I do? In my attempt at the link at beginning of the page, this did not happpen.
I did not change any file downloaded from git repo.

**Folder tree**

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── org
│   │   │       └── arquillian
│   │   │           └── example
│   │   │               └── Game.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── META-INF
│   │           └── persistence.xml
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── org
│       │       └── arquillian
│       │           └── example
│       │               └── GamePersistenceTest.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   ├── arquillian.launch
│       │   ├── arquillian.xml
│       │   └── jbossas-ds.xml
│       ├── resources-glassfish-embedded
│       │   ├── glassfish-resources.xml
│       │   ├── logging.properties
│       │   └── test-persistence.xml
│       ├── resources-glassfish-remote
│       │   └── test-persistence.xml
│       └── resources-jbossas-managed
│           └── test-persistence.xml
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │   │   ├── maven
    │   │   │   └── org.arquillian.example
    │   │   │       └── arquillian-persistence-tutorial
    │   │   │           ├── pom.properties
    │   │   │           └── pom.xml
    │   │   └── persistence.xml
    │   └── org
    │       └── arquillian
    │           └── example
    │               └── Game.class
    └── test-classes
        ├── arquillian.launch
        ├── arquillian.xml
        ├── glassfish-resources.xml
        ├── jbossas-ds.xml
        ├── logging.properties
        ├── org
        │   └── arquillian
        │       └── example
        │           └── GamePersistenceTest.class
        └── test-persistence.xml

30 directories, 24 files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_Game` class in that example is generated by the Hibernate JPA 2 metamodel generator (`hibernate-jpamodelgen`) that is defined as a dependency in the project POM. You'll now need to generate the metamodel by employing one the options outlined in the [metamodel generator reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-usage).

You could use Eclipse itself by configuring the annotation processing phase. Or you could modify the POM to use the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration specified in the guide, to run as part of your build.

Comment: I followed the Eclipse section of the guide, but I got no positive effects

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e325
It seems I am forced to modify the pom.xml file. Do you agree?

Comment: Have you added the modelgen JAR to the factory path?

Comment: There is the dependency in pom.xml, should not be enough?

Comment: No. You're configuring the compiler setting of the project beyond what m2e is capable of. Thats why you need to configure how Eclipse should compile (and process) the sources of your project. Note that these settings are likely to be ignored when you run your Maven build, so if you want your Maven build to create the generated classes, you should do this in your POM. If you want to create the classes once (and check them into SCM later) instead of letting Maven recreate them, then configure only your IDE.

Comment: Assuming that I am a very new Java EE user, what do you suggest me to do between the two choices you explained? I am really confused, expecially because I started studying Arquillian to make easier the development of my JSF/JPA project instead it seems that the complessity is increasing :-(

Comment: I think that is a new question :) But to answer it as best in a comment, this depends on how your project evolves. If the data model is stable, then it is better to generate the JPA metamodel once, commit it to SCM so that build and deployment can be done with just a plain compiler instead of requiring an annotation processor. Note that, the JPA metamodel introduces complexity that might not be worth it; it allows you to reference properties of entities natively in Java without using quoted Strings. You could avoid this and lose some auto-complete goodness.